# java volatile objects in non volatile objects

Tags: java, list, concurrency

```
// structure is like this, but not exact formation.
class queue
{
    volatile List<pieceOfWork> worksWaiting;
}

List<queue> qs; //  pieceOfWork has only some primitive arrays and strings.
```

Is it safe to read/write(not destroy, not create) elements of "Qs" from N threads at the same time?

"WorksWaiting" is meant to synchronize between controller thread(1 or 2) and a controlled thread (N) while N controlleds reading/writing to Queues concurrently.

Deletion/creation of queue will be made of controller threads.

Thanks you.

```
 th read   th write 
(cpu sse) (gpu opencl executor)
 ^         ^
 |         |
 W W W W W W  ....w<--- controller thread adding new works to queue and
                                                  deleting finished ones.
                                               also splits a work item if 
                                             it is not finished in short time.
```

Comment: Neither `WorksWaiting` nor `Qs` have been initialized, so it's unclear if a thread-safe list implementation is used there. Apart from that: Variable names should be lower case in java. And `Queueue` should probably be `Queue` instead.

Comment: Its just java's own list, not my implementation.

Comment: `List` is just an interface, not an implementation. What concrete implementation are you assigning to `worksWaiting` and `qs`?

Comment: Just a class having some arrays and strings, nothing more. Im meaning the pieceofwork part.

Comment: One more try: In your code, `qs` is `null` as you've not assigned anything to it yet. Somewhere in your code you must create a new list instance and assign it to `qs` via `qs = new ...`. So what kind of object do you create there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it safe to read/write(not destroy, not create) elements of "Qs" from N threads at the same time?

No. Is not.

See the next situation.

```
Thread 1                Thread 2

qs.add(queue1);      qs.delete(queue1); 
...                  ...
qs.add(queue100);    qs.delete(queue100);
```

You add  concurrently and delete objects to **non-synchronized** `List`.

If we assume that you both try to remove and add to the list object, you get [ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) because your `List` was not synchronized and threads will be try to work with same object. Doesn't matter which object you store in `List<queue>` because this list is outer object and he **non-synchronized.**

But. Your queue class is save-thread to the next situation :

```
queue qs = new queue();
```

and

```
Thread 1                                   Thread 2

qs.worksWaiting.add(pieceOfWork1);      qs.worksWaiting.delete(pieceOfWork1); 
...                                     ...
qs.worksWaiting.add(pieceOfWork100);    qs.worksWaiting.delete(pieceOfWork100);
```

And in this situation synchronization will works.

---

So if you want synch elements in your `List` you need to create a class which extends from `List` and synchronize `add()` and `delete()` methods.

Comment: Do you mean it is better to use only a single List (not nested) and make its elements("pieceofwork") volatile instead?

Comment: I am anticipating your question :) Look for an updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the *referece* to queue doesn't change (ie you don't create and use a new queue during execution), it doesn't have to be volatile (it makes no difference). Likewise, if the reference to the list inside queue doesn't change (ie you don't create and use a new list during execution) the list doesn't have to be volatile (it also makes no difference)

What *does* matter is that the *list* is a threadsafe implementation - whose internal variables are volatile and whose code is synchronised as required etc, because it's the references the list is holding (to the work objects) and its internals that will be mutated and these changes need to be visible to all threads (volatile).

Your code is irrelevant - it's the *list* that needs to be threadsafe.

Answer (score 2):

Objects are not volatile. *Variables* are volatile. It is safe to play with the variable `worksWaiting`. It is not safe to play with the object it refers to unless it is documented as thread-safe or you synchronize all access to it correctly.

Comment: Do you mean i can change the class instance itself(workswaiting) but not its individual fields(strings, arrays, etc...)? So volatileness is not passed to fields? Do I need synchronized(this){...} in its referring thread??

Comment: You can change the *variable*, i.e. set it to null or to a different object, and this will be seen correctly by all threads if it's declared `volatile`. You need to syncrhonize access to the *object* if it isn't thread-safe, as I stated.